# php remove xml node with DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, domdocument

*[update because of unclear question]
thanks for pointing this out @hakre*

The problem I have is that with those script i have:

1. or it cannot remove xml node i want
2. or it removes the node, but it doesnt save it file

i have this xml document:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
    <Document>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Chelsea</name>
            <Snippet>London</Snippet>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>-0.2, 51.2,0.000000</coordinates>
            </Point>
            <id>1</id>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <name>World</name>
            <Snippet>Willingdon </Snippet>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>-0.2,50.2,0.000000</coordinates>
            </Point>
            <id>2</id>
        </Placemark>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

and with this javascript i call delete.php:

```
function send2del(d){
            $.ajax({
                url : 'delete.php',
                type : 'POST',
                data : { what : $(d).data('id') },
                success : function(){
                       $(d).closest('tr').fadeOut('slow');
                }
            });
            return false;
        };
```

and i am trying to remove Placemark, using ID, here is my delete.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['what'])) { 
    $id = $_POST['what']; 
    $doc = new DOMDocument; 
    $doc->load('placemarks.xml');

    $shops = $doc->getElementsByTagName('Placemark');
    foreach ($shops as $shop) {
        $ids = $shop->getElementsByTagName('id');
        if ($ids->item(0)->nodeValue == $id) {
            $shop->parentNode->removeChild($shop);
        } 
    }
    echo $doc->saveXML();
  }  
?>
```

But it does not work.
I tried to us simpleXML, but with no success. Can you give me some guidelines about this problem? Or if you can help me with simpleXML solution, i would be very grateful.

Comment: You need to debug your code. E.g. is the value transferred to the PHP script and available there in the format you expect it to be? This is best done with a step-debugger like xdebug btw., you can look inside the program while it runs and go through step-by-step looking at all the variables and how they change etc..

Comment: it seems that it gets param that i need, `foreach ($shops as $shop) {
        $ids = $shop->getElementsByTagName('id');
        if ($ids->item(0)->nodeValue == $id) {
            echo "i found it: ".$shop->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0)->nodeValue;
        } 
    }` gives me result i expect. just i dont know hot to remove Placemark node, and save it.

Comment: You need to use the `save` method, not `saveXML`. See http://php.net/domdocument.save . And btw, this was totally not clear to me from your question, I had the impression the element wasn't removed from the document, but you're just concerned about saving, right?

Comment: thanks, maybe i wasnt clear enough. and to be honest i didnt know if an element was removed. so i wasnt sure were the problem was. i had `echo $doc->saveXML();` but when i use `$doc->save('placemarks.xml')` it works.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code. It removes the element based on it. Maybe the issue resides with the ids used?

Before and After:

BEFORE:

```
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
<document>
<placemark>
<name>Chelsea</name>
<snippet>London</snippet>
<point>
<coordinates>-0.2, 51.2,0.000000</coordinates>
</point>
<id>1</id>
</placemark>
<placemark>
<name>World</name>
<snippet>Willingdon </snippet>
<point>
<id>2</id>
</placemark>
</document>
</kml>
```

AFTER:

```
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
<document>
<placemark>
<name>World</name>
<snippet>Willingdon </snippet>
<point>
<coordinates>-0.2,50.2,0.000000</coordinates>
</point>
<id>2</id>
</placemark>
</document>
</kml>
```

Comment: That's more a comment than an answer.

Comment: i think my id param is ok, this one return what i am expecting. `$shop->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0)->nodeValue;` for some reason i cannot save this xml. i checked permission to file and everyone can write.